# JPA, scope, and autosave?

Tags: jpa

I am using JPA and lets say I do something like this

```
public class MoRun extends Thread {...
public void run() {
    final EntityManagerFactory emFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("pu");
    EntityManager manager = emFactory.createEntityManager();
    manager.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.COMMIT);
    someMethod(manager);
    ...
}


public void someMethod(EntityManager manager){
    Query query = manager.createNamedQuery("byStates");
    List<State> list = query.getResultList(); 
    for (State state : list) {
        if(someTest)
            state.setValue(...)
    }
...
}
```

So for those objects that pass "someTest" and values are updated are those changes automatically persisted to the db even though there is no transaction and I don't explicitly "manager.save(state)" the object?  I ask because it seems like it is and I was wondering if the flush is doing it?

Comment: How/where do you run this code? What `transaction-type` do you use (RESOURCE_LOCAL or TRANSACTION)?

Answer (score 1):

According to the javadoc of [`FlushMode`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/persistence/FlushModeType.html) (I'm assuming this is a JPA 1.0 question), and as pointed out by @Konrad:

> If there is no transaction active, the persistence provider must not flush to the database.

Since you're very likely using a `transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL"` for your persistence unit, since I don't see any `begin`/`commit` surrounding your calls to your `EntityManager` (which is not good, more on this just after), for me there is no transaction active so I wouldn't expect anything to be flushed.

Anyway, as reminded in the nice [JPA Concepts](http://openejb.apache.org/3.0/jpa-concepts.html) page:

> - With `<persistence-unit transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">`
>     **you** are responsible for `EntityManager`
>     (PersistenceContext/Cache) creating
>     and tracking...
>
>   - You **must** use
>       the EntityManagerFactory to get an
>       EntityManager
>   - The resulting
>       `EntityManager` instance is a
>       PersistenceContext/Cache
>   - An
>       **`EntityManagerFactory`** can be injected via the
>       **`@PersistenceUnit`** annotation only (not @PersistenceContext)
>   - You are
>       **not** allowed to use @PersistenceContext to refer to a unit
>       of type RESOURCE_LOCAL
>   - You
>       **must** use the **`EntityTransaction`** API to begin/commit around every call to your
>       EntityManger
>   - Calling
>       `entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager()`
>       twice results in **two** separate
>       EntityManager instances and therefor
>       **two** separate PersistenceContexts/Caches.
>   - It is
>       **almost never** a good idea to have more than one **instance** of an
>       EntityManager in use (don't create a
>       second one unless you've destroyed the
>       first)

So, in my opinion, you should **fix** your code here, there is no real point at wondering about unexpected behavior if your code is not correct. Just performs calls to your `EntityManager` inside a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know there is no transaction? Are you using it from EJB? In that case I bet there is a transaction.

From docs (http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/persistence/FlushModeType.html):

> If FlushModeType.COMMIT is set, the
>   effect of updates made to entities in
>   the persistence context upon queries
>   is unspecified.
>
> If there is no transaction active, the
>   persistence provider must not flush to
>   the database.

If you are in transaction, attached entities (i.e. those loaded in the same transaction) are automatically recorded to database.

Comment: I am creating the entitymanager (right before I call the method above I do this EntityManager manager = emFactory.createEntityManager();) myself, so I know there are no other transactions.